# How to instantiate prefab outside Resources folder?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to developing a tool to help me "remember" all my prefabs / fbx assets.

My assets are almost in a subFolder (for instnace) "3d models" .

I've developed a routine to get all "*.prefab" or "*.fbx" files and store it in a List / Array.

Now, in a test scenem, i want to instantiate them (using 2 buttons: previous prefab and next prefab).

Using :

```
_currentPrefab = Instantiate ( Resources.Load (prefabs [currentPrefabIndex].ToString(), typeof(GameObject)), SpawnGameObject.transform.position, new Quaternion(0,0,0,0)) as GameObject;
```

Give me an error because (i'm pretty sure) my prefab is outside Resource folder.

So my question is: how can i Instantiate my prefab outside that folder ? Is there a way ?

Thanks

Comment: You can do this in the editor, but in a compiled build only the things referenced in a scene or in a Resources folder gets included in the build. Files that aren't referenced in a built scene or in a Resources folder don't get included in the build, so the data is physically not there to load. Can you clarify the context in which you need to do this?

Comment: My scenario is the following: i've a "medium" sized project with "tons" of imported assets. I don't even remember what i've imported, so i need a "test" scene that get all "prefab" files recursevely in all folders, so i can instantiate them, watch them, then pass to next ...

Comment: noticed this went up for a bounty. Is there a part of my answer that was unclear? what is the name of the list/array of your fbx's. you can do either way I described. I will update to show the instantiate part if you need?

Comment: I notice you've added a bounty to this question. Can you comment to clarify whether the existing answer works for your needs, or if you need something it doesn't cover?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can loop through your list and instantiate into the hierarchy or a more efficient way would be load in a custom editor window then when you find the one you want you can instantiate into the scene.

you want to load them using either `AssetDatabase` or the `Directory` class. then you can instantiate the result.

```
for int i = 0; i<MyFBXPaths.Length; i ++)
{
    Object _asset;  //each string path would look something like this Assets/YourFolderToAsset/yourasset
    _asset = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(MyFBXPaths[i], typeof(Object))
    //edit added Instantiation using your variable for clarity
    _currentPrefab = Instantiate (_asset,SpawnGameObject.transform.position,Quaternion.identity);

}
```

or

```
  var myDirectoryContents = Directory.GetFiles(MyFBXPaths[i] + "/");
            for (int c = 0; c < myDirectoryContents.Length; c++)
            {
               //do stuff

            }
```

to break it down even further to do what you ask all you want is the path. you can easily obtain that for example `Directory.GetFiles("Assets/3dModels/")` will return a array of the paths. 
a example of loading directly without the array would be

```
_asset = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/3dModels/3dmodel1.prefab", typeof(Object)) as GameObject;
_currentPrefab = Instantiate (_asset,SpawnGameObject.transform.position,Quaternion.identity);
```

both of those classes you can create or manage directories and files within the project without being in the resources folder. Be sure you are `using Unity.Editor` for `AssetDatabase` and or `System.IO` for `Directory`

Comment: Does not maintain prefab link

Comment: Nowadays I would recommend looking into using the addressable assets system instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are a 2 main ways to instantiate a prefab in Unity.

First, you can have an object in your scene that holds a reference to that prefab.  Usually you have a reference to a single prefab you want to load, but you could just as easily have a GameObject array full of all your prefabs.  If you want to get fancy about it you could even fill this array procedurally during scene build.  When Unity loads the scene, it will loads copies of those prefabs into memory, and you can call instantiate on them.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
   [SerializeField] private GameObject bulletPrefab;

   public void Fire() {
      var bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab);
   }
}
```

The second, and vastly inferior, way is to use resources.  Resources, as you discovered, must be in the Resources directory.  However, you can load your prefab reference at runtime and instantiate it at runtime.  I wouldn't do this often, it's something that would best go in Start.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
   [SerializeField] private string bulletPrefabPath;
   private GameObject bulletPrefab;

   void Start() {
      bulletPrefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>(bulletPrefabPath);
   }

   public void Fire() {
      var bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab);
   }
}
```

There is another way that can be used to some success as well.  If you have a set of prefabs that's used across multiple scenes, you can store references to them in a ScriptableObject.  A ScriptableObject is like a MonoBehaviour but it exists outside of any scene.  Your MonoBehaviours can then have a reference to that ScriptableObject, which holds references to the prefabs.  The prefabs will be loaded into memory either when Unity starts, or when a scene starts where one object holds a reference to the ScriptableObject.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName="PrefabCollection", menuName="PrefabCollection")]
public class PrefabHolder : ScriptableObject {
   public GameObject[] prefabs;
}

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
   [SerializeField] private PrefabHolder bulletPrefabs;

   public void Fire() {
      // Fire a random bullet prefab
      var prefabIdx = Random.Range(0, bulletPrefabs.prefabs.Length - 1;
      var bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefabs.prefabs[prefabIdx]);
   }
}
```

Comment: There's a third way, called [Asset Bundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) which supersedes and deprecates `Resources.Load`.

Comment: Judging by the comment thread above, where OP says 'I don't even remember what I've imported, so I need a "test" scene that get all "prefab" files recursively in all folders,' I think they need a solution for their own workflow in-editor, so we may not be limited to methods that work in-game in release builds.

Comment: Another thing to note is anything in the Resources folder get turned into a single serialized file, that will be loaded as soon as the application is loaded even if the files aren't going to be used for a while, so the bigger it gets the worse load times will be.